# Reference request: sheaves on the site of d-manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, sheaf-theory

I believe I know how to prove the following results.  I also know to whom to cite fancy-shmancy results that have these as a very special case.  **My question is:** what are the correct citations for these versions?  **Pre-question:** Are the results correctly stated?

**Version 1**

Let $\mathrm{Man}_d$ denote the category of $d$-dimensional smooth manifolds and local diffeomorphisms — what are often called the "étale" maps of manifolds.  Let us say that a presheaf $F: \mathrm{Man}_d^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Set}$ is a *topological sheaf* if it is local for the usual (or "étale") topology on $\mathrm{Man}_d$ and also takes homotopic maps in $\mathrm{Man}_d$ to equal functions in $\mathrm{Set}$.  Any topological sheaf $F$ then induces a $\mathbb Z/2 = \pi_0(\hom(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)$-action on $F(\mathbb R^d)$.  The claim is that $F$ is determined by the set $F(\mathbb R^d)$ with its $\mathbb Z/2$-action.

**Version 2**

Same thing, but with embeddings: replace $\mathrm{Man}_d$ by the category $\mathrm{Emb}_d$ of $d$-dimensional manifolds and open embeddings; use the Weiss topology.

**Version 1.$\infty$ and 2.$\infty$**

Same thing but replace $\mathrm{Set}$ with $\mathrm{Spaces}$, use homotopy sheaves, and classify in terms of homotopy $\hom(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d) \simeq O(d)$-actions.

Comment: I guess I am also interested in versions 1.1 and 2.1, where you study stacks of (1-)groupoids rather than fully-infinitized homotopy sheaves/stacks.

Comment: Version 1 follows instantly from the existence of differentiable good open covers, which is definitely a folklore result.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Ah, good, and googling "differentiable good open covers" results in an nlab page with textbook references. Do you want to make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1 is a simple corollary of the existence
of [differentiable good open covers](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/good+open+cover#DifferentiablyGoodOpenCover), i.e., covers whose finite intersections are diffeomorphic to R^n.

This shows that sheaves on the site of n-manifolds and etale maps are equivalent to sheaves on the site with a single object R^n.
The fact that the space of endomorphisms of R^n in this category is homotopy equivalent to O(n) completes the proof.

Comment: Dmitri: this is probably not helpful. Theo started his question by "I believe I know how to prove the following results". He was specifically asking for references.

Comment: @AndréHenriques: There are references in the link I supplied.

Comment: @AndréHenriques: Although I can see why one might be confused: a visited link is almost invisible in the new style.

Comment: @AndréHenriques Given that I asked Dmitri to make his comment and answer, I think it reasonable to accept the answer, also since a few days is plenty for a question like this.  In the best of worlds I would like original references, but Dmitri makes a convincing argument that Version 1, at least, is a folk theorem; the linked citations also answer my ulterior goal, which was to have something to cite that isn't obviously overkill.